# Objective c NSDate taking off 1 hour from parsed date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I am parsing the following string format: "29/09/2010 12:45:00" with the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateTime = [[df dateFromString:dateAndTime]];
```

But the NSDate object then contains the following: 2010/09/29 11:45:00

Does anyone have any idea why it is taking off an hour?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

What time zone are you in?  Unless otherwise specified, `NSDateFormatter` assumes that the string it's parsing is in the `GMT +0000` timezone.  If you're in `GMT -0100` (one hour west of GMT), then it's going to show the time as one hour off (since you're ignoring the time zone when printing).